# Analytical solution of a (matrix) 1st-order different equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Regarding a matrix differential equation
\begin{equation}
i\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0(t)\\
c_1(t)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A^* e^{-i\theta t}\\
A e^{i\theta t} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0(t)\\
c_1(t)
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $\theta$ are time-independent variables, is the analytical solution available for a given initial condition? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the matrix does not commute with itself at different times, one could write down the formal solution as a time ordered exponential. Probably it simplifies due to the specific matrix you have here. Simpler way: write the coupled differential equations for $c_0(t)$ and $c_1(t)$. Differentiate those, then substitute to get decoupled second order equations; which turn out to be the damped oscillator equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Using the Laplace transform we have

$$
\cases{
isC_0(s) = A^* C_1(s+i\theta)+c_0(0)\\
isC_1(s) = A C_0(s-i\theta)+c_1(0)
}
$$

but

$$
i(s+i\theta)C_1(s+i\theta) = A C_0(s)+c_1(0)
$$

then

$$
isC_0(s) = \frac{A^*(AC_0(s)+c_1(0))}{i(s+i\theta)}+c_0(0)
$$

or

$$
C_0(s) = -\frac{\frac{A^*c_1(0)}{s+i\theta}+ic_0(0)}{s+\frac{A^*A}{s+i\theta}}
$$

analogous development do obtain $C_1(s)$.   After that the inversion is direct.

$$
c_0(t) = e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \theta t} \left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{4 \|A\|^2+\theta ^2}\right) (c_0(0) \theta -2 A^* c_1(0))}{\sqrt{4
   \|A\|^2+\theta ^2}}-i c_0(0) \cos \left(\frac{t}{2} \sqrt{4 \|A\|^2+\theta ^2}\right)\right)
$$